# Scene Builder included File does not resize with parent

Tags: javafx, resize, include, scenebuilder

What setting is needed for a included File in Scene Builder to resize with parent.
http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150726/fdufuvj5.png

Edit:

Files or code?

Here are the files as rar:

http://www89.zippyshare.com/v/9F5q5ZJJ/file.html

Comment: Could you post the fxml files?

Comment: File or code do you need?

Comment: you are in the fx scene builder, i do not use it much but i think it does not translate better on whats happening, but you can try autoSize() or something like that, also resizing is sometimes done by you, you have to notify them sometimes ,exceptions to some Nodes

Comment: After a while i could fix that problem without using autoSize(). I set the anchors of my splitpane to "0"(null). At least the included FXML resize to left and right correctly, but not to bottom or top because its included in a VBox. I just need to change it and everything works fine.